# Avoiding nesting two for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Please have a look at the code below:

```
import string
from collections import defaultdict



first_complex=open( "residue_a_chain_a_b_backup.txt", "r" )
first_complex_lines=first_complex.readlines()
first_complex_lines=map( string.strip, first_complex_lines )
first_complex.close()

second_complex=open( "residue_a_chain_a_c_backup.txt", "r" )
second_complex_lines=second_complex.readlines()
second_complex_lines=map( string.strip, second_complex_lines )
second_complex.close()
list_1=[]
list_2=[]
for x in first_complex_lines:
    if x[0]!="d":
        list_1.append( x )
for y in second_complex_lines:
    if y[0]!="d":
        list_2.append( y ) 
j=0
list_3=[]      
list_4=[]
for a in list_1:
    pass
    for b in list_2:
        pass
        if a==b:
            list_3.append( a )    

kvmap=defaultdict( int )
for k in list_3:
    kvmap[k]+=1 
print kvmap
```

Normally I use izip or izip_longest to club two for loops, but this time the length of the files are different. I don't want a None entry. If I use the above method, the run time becomes incremental and useless. How am I supposed to get the two for loops going?

Cheers,
Chavanak

Comment: By the way, your code is full of extraneous cruft.  Your file names mean nothing to us, and make your code unrunnable.  Also, j is never used.  Also the kvmap stuff is irrelevant.  If you trim out the unnecessary details, it will be easier for people to see what you are asking.  It will also often be easier for you to see what is really happening with your code.

Comment: Is the order in which the words are put into list_3 important? Also, are there or could there potentially be repeated words in list_1 or list_2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to convert `list_2` to a set, and check for membership:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'big', 'list']
list_2 = ['another', 'big', 'list']

target_set = set(list_2)

for a in list_1:
    if a in target_set:
         print a
```

Outputs:

```
big
list
```

A set gives you the advantage of O(1) access time to determine membership, so you only have to read all the way through `list_2` once (when creating the set).  Thereafter, each comparison happens in constant time.

Answer (score 3):

The following code perform the same tasks as yours with greater conciseness, directness, and speed:

```
with open('residue_a_chain_a_b_backup.txt', 'r') as f:
  list1 = [line for line in f if line[0] != 'd']
with open('residue_a_chain_a_c_backup.txt', 'r') as f:
  list2 = [line for line in f if line[0] != 'd']
set2 = set(list2)
list3 = [line for line in list1 if line in set2]
```

the following histogramming of lint3 into `kvmap` is already fine in your code.  (In Python 2.5, to use the `with` statement, you need to start your module with `from __future__ import with_statement`; in 2.6, no need for that "import from the future", though it does no harm if you want to leave it in).

Answer (score 2):

Is it the intersection of two set you want, if so you can use the set interaction operation:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'big', 'list']
list_2 = ['another', 'big', 'list']

intersection = (set(list_1) & set(list_2))
```

After running this, `interaction` is a `set` containing the common items of `list_1` and `list_2`.

Answer (score 1):

Refining Alex's code very slightly:

```
with open('residue_a_chain_a_c_backup.txt', 'r') as f:
  set2 = set([line.strip() for line in f if line[0] != 'd'])

with open('residue_a_chain_a_b_backup.txt', 'r') as f:
  list1 = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip() in set2]
```

Comment: Refining it a little more, if you're using a context processor, you're obviously python > 2.4, which means you can use a generator expression in your set function, and save yourself a list creation: `set2 = set(line.strip for line in f if line[0] != 'd')`.

Comment: For some reason I talked myself out of that, but I can't now see why.  Do you need a second set of parentheses?  I wonder that about generator comprehensions a lot.